# How do I update my Samsung Galaxy Europa?

Tags: updates, samsung-europa

What is the latest official firmware for Samsung Galaxy Europa? I am currently on 2.2 Froyo at the moment. Can I update it using Samsung Kies, or do I need to update from somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

No, you are currently running the latest version of Android for your device without flashing a custom ROM.

If you are interested in flashing a custom ROM a port of CyanogenMod 10.1 (Android version 4.2.1 Jelly Bean) has been made for your device, all information and installation guide can be found [here](http://madteam.co/forum/development-8/%28dev%29-cyanogenmod-10-1-galaxy5-port-%28androidarmv6%29/).